# Train collision problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Train $A$ takes $4$ hours and Train $B$ takes $5$ hours to cover the total length of a track. If they start simultaneously at opposite ends of the same track, at what time will they collide?

Answer (score 2):

A non-algebraic way.

The ratio of the speeds of $A:B = 5:4$ (reverse the ratio of the times taken to traverse the track). That is the ratio of the distances travelled by the trains in a fixed interval of time.

So at collision, train $A$ would have travelled $\frac{5}{5+4} = \frac 59$ of the track, which would take it $\frac 59 \cdot 4 = \frac{20}{9}$ hours.

Working it out for the other train would give you the same answer of course.

Answer (score 0):

Let the total length of the train be $20x$.

Then the speed of Train A is Distance/Time=$20x/4=5x$.

Similarly, the speed of Train B is $4x$.

$4x+5x=9x$.

Thus, the time taken for them to collide is $20x/9x=20/9$ hours. (approx 2 hours 13 min)